# How to create a singleton object A from inside B's method by preventing direct access of A from A?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

In a static library, I have two classes A, B inheriting from NSObject. I want to create an object of A in some method of B. User should be able to access reference of A only through B and only single object of A and b should be created. After user add static library in their Xcode project, they shouldn't be able to created an object of A directly, due to which I have raised an exception in the init of A. But, after doing this I cannot create an object of A in B also. I don't want to create shared instance of A, that will allow the library user to access A, before B is created. My main goal is to create an object of A inside B, only after B is created and user should be able to access the A object through a property of B

```
@implementation A
//This will prevent library user to create A
- (instancetype)init {
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
   return nil;
}

@implementation B

- (void)initialiseSDK{

   A *a = [B sharedA]; //won't work, A's init raises exception


+ (A *)sharedA{

    static dispatch_once_t d;
    static OncamAccount *sharedA = nil;

    dispatch_once(&d, ^{
        sharedA = [[A alloc]init];   //A's init raise exception
    });
    return shared;
}

+ (B *)sharedB{

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static OnCamSDK *sharedB = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedB = [[B alloc] init];

    });
    return sharedB;
}
```

If I remove the exception from A's init, then I think user will be able to create an object of A directly, which I don't want.

Comment: You could create a variant of `init` that you don't publicize, like `initForB` and leave your current `init` as is.  Someone who wanted to call the new one could probably figure it out but, if you're just trying to stop incidental/accidental use, it could work.  (If you're trying to prevent Objective-C "hackers" it would be more difficult.)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000571/how-can-i-make-it-private-members-or-methods-of-class-so-that-it-can-be-accessed  It's close to what you are talking about.  Basically dealing with private classes inside static libraries.

Comment: @PhillipMills If I don't make initForB public inside A, how will I access it in B, and thus how will I create A from B.

Comment: You can create a category for A that only B knows about.

Comment: @PhillipMills Creating category is a good idea as I don't want to expose the initForB in header file. Thanks Phillip

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that gives `A` more control of what's going on:

Declare variables in `A.m` outside the implementation.

```
static BOOL initialized = NO;
static NSLock *initLock;
```

Add initialization code to support locking.

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    initLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
}
```

Make the `init` conditional.

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    [initLock lock];
    if (initialized) {
        [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
        return nil;
    }
    initialized = YES;
    [initLock unlock];
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}
```